# Change a list name with a string

Tags: python, global-variables

(Another begynner question)

I need to extract several list with values from several txt files (two list from each file).
I made a function to extrac the values I need, but I don't know how to name the list so that they include the name of the original file. For example:

filename+'*'+measurements
filename+'*'+dates

the first problem is that these names are strings, and I'm not sure how to convert them to the name of the lists.

the second problem is that doing this into a function the names are not global, and I can't access the lists later on. If I write global in front of the name of the variable, I get an error.

```
def open_catch_down ():

    file = raw_input('Give the name of the file:')

    infile = open(file,'r')
    lines = infile.readlines()
    infile.close()

    global dates
    global values
    dates = []
    values = []


    import datetime

    for line in lines[1:]:
        words = line.split()
        year = int(words[0])
        month = int(words[1])
        day = int(words[2])
        hour = int(words[3])
        minute = int(words[4])
        second = int(words[5])
        date = datetime.datetime(year,month,day,hour,minute,second)
        dates.append(date)
        value = float(words[6])
        values.append(value)  

    vars()[file + '_' + 'values'] = values


open_catch_down ()

print vars()[file + '_' + 'values']
```

Then I get the error:

```
print vars()[file + '_' + 'values']
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'type' and 'str'

Comment: We need more information, for instance you didn't even list the language or environment you are working in.

Comment: Are you asking to re-name a variable? Many languages wont let you do that. Still not sure what language you are working in, but just putting global in front of a variable wont always do this, you need to look up this languages scoping methods.

Comment: Post the code and the exact error your seeing.

Comment: Ok, the idea it to get extracted a list with numbers from a txt file with python.

Comment: The name of this list has to refer to the name of the file. That's my first problem.

Comment: You could just use a dictionary for this which maps your name to a list. Dynamically naming the variable is probably not what you actually want or need.

Comment: Your *real* first problem is thinking you want to make the name of the list carry information. :^)  Use a dictionary instead.

Comment: I think i grasp what you want to do (actually making the lists globally available by their file name) but I wouldnt do it that way. Explaining why would exceed the comment space so i will reduce my answere to an alternative: Put them into a dictionary. A dictionary or map is exactly the type of collection your looking for. It makes dynamic objects available by a key (which can actually be of any type, but most often strings are used). A quite funny thing: Global vars are also stored in a dictionary called `__dict__`. By adding a object there you make it available as a global var.

Comment: Thaks guys. It seems it is more logical to do this with a dictionary. The problem I see with dictionaries is that they make a mess of my lists and I would like to keep them in order to use indexes in my calculations... On the other hand, I don't know if it is possible to plot dictionaries (with keys in one axis and values in the other)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your usage of `vars` is wrong, without arguments it just returns the `locals` dict which is not writable. You could use `globals` instead.

Now to your exception... the `file` variable isn't in the scope of your print statement:

```
def open_catch_down():
    file = raw_input(...) #this variable is local to the function
    [...]

print file                #here, file references the built-in file type
```

As `file` is the name of pythons built-in type for file handling, the `file` in the print statement references this class, which leads to the error. If you named the variable `filename` instead of `file` (which you should do because it is always a bad idea to shadow built-in names), you would have gotten an `UnboundLocalError`. The simplest solution for your example would be to make your function return the file name and save it in the outer scope:

```
def open_catch_down():
    filename = raw_input(...) #your file name

    #... rest of the code

    return filename

filename = open_catch_down()
print filename
```